# Wondering how I can put a chunk of code into a separate function and share variables between them

Tags: c++, console-application

I am currently trying to build a simple shop keeper program that you can buy items from. The items are stored into an array and there is a maximum amount of items that you put into the array.

Whilst my program works, I am unsure as to how I can share the variables between the two functions

```
// ConsoleApplication2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int PurchaseItems()
{
    //I'd like to switch statement to go in here
}

int main()
{
    const int maxItems = 5; //Maximum number of items in inventory
    int userChoice = 0, //User control for menus
        goldPieces = 75, //How many gold pieces player has
        numbItems = 0; //Current number of items in inventory

std::string inventory[maxItems]; //Inventory

//Items in inventory when player begins
inventory[numbItems++] = "Sword";
inventory[numbItems++] = "Cloak";
inventory[numbItems++] = "Boots";

std::cout << "Greeting traveller! Feel free to browse my wares."; //Greeting message

do
{
    //List of things to buy
    std::cout << "\n1: Axe - 25gp.\n2: Mace - 30gp. \n3: Helmet - 20gp. \n4: Exit.\n";
    std::cin >> userChoice; //Reads user input

    switch (userChoice)
    {
    case 1:
        if (goldPieces >= 25 && numbItems < maxItems) //If userhas enough gold and available inventory space
        {
            inventory[numbItems++] = "Axe"; //Add to inventory
            goldPieces -= 25; //Remove gold from player
        }

        else
        {
            std::cout << "You do not meet the requirements.";
        }
    break;

    case 2: 
        if (goldPieces >= 30 && numbItems < maxItems)
        {
            inventory[numbItems++] = "Mace";
            goldPieces -= 30;
        }

        else
        {
            std::cout << "You do not meet the requirements.";
        }
    break;

    case 3: 
        if (goldPieces >= 20 && numbItems < maxItems)
        {
            inventory[numbItems++] = "Helmet";
            goldPieces -= 20;
        }

        else
        {
            std::cout << "You do not meet the requirements.";
        }
    break;

    case 4:
        std::cout << "You have left the shop.\n";
    break;

    default:
        std::cout << "Please enter sufficient data.";
        break;
    }

    //List inventory
    std::cout << "Inventory: \n";

    for (int i = 0; i < numbItems; i++)
    {
        std::cout << inventory[i] << "\n";
    }
} while (userChoice != 4);




//keep window open
std::string barn;
std::cin >> barn;

return 0;
```

}

Whilst I thought I could have it so that the gold is handled in the other function, I am unsure on how to get the 'numbItems' & 'maxItems' variables accross.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I did use a singular parameter but I hadn't copied all the necessary code into the other function which was leading to my confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you don't want to use parameters? Also since this is C++ you should use a vector instead of an array.

```
int PurchaseItems(std::vector<std::string>& items, /*more parameters*/)
{
    //Use items here
    items.push_back("Axe"); //Buy an axe
}

//elsewhere
std::vector<std::string> items;
int result = PurchaseItems(items, /*more arguments*/);
```

Comment: I am currently going through this book: http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/1435457420/ref=s9_simh_gw_p14_d0_i1?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=desktop-1&pf_rd_r=0WYNZSG5JX7RRQSHDM8C&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=577047927&pf_rd_i=desktop

And using C++ principles and practices for the theory. I did wonder why it was using an array in the game programming book. 

Which is said to use arrays but thank you for saying because it could be bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two choices - either pass arguments to functions (and return values) or use global variables.

Global variables are much frown upon (and rightfuly so!), since they make the program hard to mainain, comprehend, test and debug. Hence, you need to pass arguments. Here is the one (not the only one!) way you can do this:

```
// I did remove max_items check for now
int PurchaseItems(std::vector<std::string>& inventory, int gold, int choice)
{
  switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        if (gold >= 25) //If userhas enough gold and available inventory space
        {
            inventory.push_back("Axe"); //Add to inventory
            gold -= 25; //Remove gold from player
        }
...
}
...
   // then later in your program:
   goldPieces = PurchaseItems(inventory, goldPieces);
```